Unexpected coordinate switching when reshaping object positions into 3D grid after flattening and integrating
I am working on processing and analyzing velocity field data from VTI files using Python. The workflow includes reading VTI files, extracting velocity data, computing object trajectories, generating the trajectories as maps, and then running different calculations. However, I'm encountering an issue where the maps seem to have misaligned axes, leading to incorrect delta calculations between neighboring grid points.
I use an integration of the np.meshgrid of the objects or particles reshape and flatten for the integration and then reshape into thedesired shape based on the domain axis. I couldn't find the point at which the x and z axis were being switched. I could tell they were being switched due to the difference from one point to the neighbour was zero along the desired axis but along the counter axis so z for x and x for z I was receiving the expected coordinate distances. The y axis was not encountering any issues.
Additionally, I noticed that if I change the x_grid to be say from 1 - 11 instead of 0 - 10 then the delta calculated there is as expected, meaning the shape I believe fits. By including 'order = F' for the reshaping, so following the Fortran-like index order, during the reshaping process, the correct axis alignment is preserved.
Why is the reshaping not working as expected unless I use the Fortran indexing? Or have I misunderstood or messed up the reshaping at a different point or in the integration?
I have been able to recreate the problem in the following snippet:
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp

x_grid = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
y_grid = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
z_grid = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
resolution = 0.01

domain_x = np.arange(x_grid.min(), x_grid.max() + resolution, resolution)
domain_y = np.arange(y_grid.min(), y_grid.max() + resolution, resolution)
domain_z = np.arange(z_grid.min(), z_grid.max() + resolution, resolution)

domain_shape = (len(domain_x), len(domain_y), len(domain_z))

#initial positions
initial_positions = np.array(np.meshgrid(domain_x, domain_y, domain_z, indexing='ij')).T.reshape(-1, 3)

def path_calc(t, y):
    return y
# Solving
t_span = (0, 1)
times = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
sol = solve_ivp(
    path_calc,
    t_span,
    initial_positions.flatten(),
    method='RK45',
    t_eval=times,
    vectorized=True
)
trajectories = sol.y.T.reshape(len(times), -1, 3)


def compute_maps(trajectories, domain_shape):
    positions_final = trajectories[-1]
    
    expected_num_positions = np.prod(domain_shape)
    actual_num_positions = positions_final.shape[0]
    
    if expected_num_positions != actual_num_positions:
        raise ValueError(f"Expected number of positions {expected_num_positions} does not match actual number {actual_num_positions}")
    
    map_x = positions_final[:, 0].reshape(domain_shape, order='F')
    map_y = positions_final[:, 1].reshape(domain_shape, order='F')
    map_z = positions_final[:, 2].reshape(domain_shape, order='F')
    
    map_x_non = positions_final[:, 0].reshape(domain_shape)
    map_y_non = positions_final[:, 1].reshape(domain_shape)
    map_z_non = positions_final[:, 2].reshape(domain_shape)
    
    maps = {
        'map_x': map_x,
        'map_y': map_y,
        'map_z': map_z,
        'map_x_non': map_x_non,
        'map_y_non': map_y_non,
        'map_z_non': map_z_non
    }

    return maps


maps = compute_maps(trajectories, domain_shape)


delta_x_calc = np.abs(maps['map_x'][1, 0, 0] - maps['map_x'][0, 0, 0])
delta_y_calc = np.abs(maps['map_y'][0, 1, 0] - maps['map_y'][0, 0, 0])
delta_z_calc = np.abs(maps['map_z'][0, 0, 1] - maps['map_z'][0, 0, 0])
delta_x_calc_non = np.abs(maps['map_x_non'][1, 0, 0] - maps['map_x_non'][0, 0, 0])
delta_y_calc_non = np.abs(maps['map_y_non'][0, 1, 0] - maps['map_y_non'][0, 0, 0])
delta_z_calc_non = np.abs(maps['map_z_non'][0, 0, 1] - maps['map_z_non'][0, 0, 0])

